# Begin reading(dequeue) from MSMQ then stop the dequeue process and then again start in C#

Tags: c#, message-queue, msmq

As per the current implementation, C# code adds messages to MSMQ and then after a particular operation is completed, I need to dequeue and start processing them. Following code is used:

```
_queue.ReceiveCompleted += new ReceiveCompletedEventHandler(RecieveQ_ReceiveCompleted);
_queue.BeginReceive();
```

However, in between the dequeue process, I would want to stop it and then again start it sometime later, depending on the user input. I came across the `EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)` method, but could not implement it correctly.

Comment: Careful, "deque" is NOT an abbreviation for "Dequeue", it actually means the "Double-Ended Queue" data structure.

Comment: Just submitted an edit to change "deque" to "dequeue" as it seems to be a genuine mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BeginReceive()` and `EndReceive()` are not for starting and stopping the queue like turning on and off a tap (or faucet).

In MSMQ, when you call `BeginReceive()`, a second thread is spawned which waits for a message to enter the queue.  When a message arrives, it calls your `RecieveQ_ReceiveCompleted` event handler.

Inside you event handler, you then call `EndReceive()` to fetch the item from the queue, and then do your processing.  Note that if another item arrives in the queue, it will not be processsed.

If you want to process queue items repeatedly, you have to call `BeginReceive()` again from within your event handler.

If you want to pause the processing after each item to wait for a signal from the user to process the next item, you will need to signal from the event handler that an item has been processed, and either the event handler or main thread will need to call `BeginReceive()` again.

Depending on your situation, you might find it easier to use the `Receive()` method instead of the asynchronous version to better control your order of operations.

References: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43h44x53(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4

> In asynchronous processing, you use BeginReceive to raise the ReceiveCompleted event when a message has been removed from the queue.
>
> The MessageQueue can then access the message by calling EndReceive(IAsyncResult).
>
> Once an asynchronous operation completes, you can call BeginPeek or BeginReceive again in the event handler to keep receiving notifications.

Hope this helps

Comment: These APIs haven't been modernized with `await`-compatible returns?  That's unfortunate.